# Concatenate constants Objective-C ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create constant NSString by concatenating strings in Obj-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060139/how-to-create-constant-nsstring-by-concatenating-strings-in-obj-c)

I have two constants that I would like to concatenate:

```
NSString * const WEBSITE_URL = @"http://192.168.1.15:3000/";
NSString * const API_URL = @"http://192.168.1.15:3000/api/";
```

Normally in other languages I would concatenate the WEBSITE_URL in API_URL, but you can't concatenate a compile time constant since stringWithFormat or anything like it is a runtime, not compile time method.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, do you want to concatenate them at compile time? If so, why? :)

Comment: So that if the root URL changes, it only needs updating in one place on one line.

Answer (score 19):

you can do this with macro 
use:

```
#define WEBSITE_URL @"http://192.168.1.15:3000/"
#define API_URL WEBSITE_URL @"api/"
```

Answer (score 9):

You could drop to the preprocessor.

```
#define WEBSITE_URL_DEF "http://192.168.1.15:3000/"

NSString * const WEBSITE_URL = @WEBSITE_URL_DEF;
NSString * const API_URL     = @WEBSITE_URL_DEF "api/";
```